# Issue with Special Characters in Retrofit 2 encoding

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

So I'm looking to make a request to our api to log in a user, however there is a section that gets encoded in the Retrofit 2 method even though its set as `encoded = true`.  The base url is `https://testapi.test.ie`  The parameter I pass as the `serverext` is `mdc.php?action=`  However even after setting `encoded = true`  the resulting request body is: `https://testapi.test.ie/mdc.php%3Faction=login_user&ts=1482924232742` where I require it to be: `https://testapi.test.ie/mdc.php?action=login_user&ts=1482924232742` So I can see the issue is the `?` symbol. Below is my retrofit method, if anyone can help with this I would appreciate it in order to achieve the correct

```
@retrofit2.http.POST("/{serverext}login_user&ts={timestamp}")
@retrofit2.http.Multipart
Call<LoginResponseModel> loginUser(@retrofit2.http.Path(value = "serverext", encoded = true) String server,
                             @retrofit2.http.Part(Constants.USER) String username,
                             @retrofit2.http.Part(Constants.PASS) String password,
                             @retrofit2.http.Path("timestamp") Long timestamp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use it incorrect. Path is path, Query is query. You need to rewrite your code to use this separately.

```
@retrofit2.http.POST("{serverext}")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<LoginResponseModel> loginUser(@retrofit2.http.Path(value = "serverext", encoded = true) String server,
                             @retrofit2.http.Field(Constants.USER) String username,
                             @retrofit2.http.Field(Constants.PASS) String password,
                             @retrofit2.http.Query("timestamp") Long timestamp, 
                             @retrofit2.http.Query("action") String action);

loginUser("mdc.php", username, pass, 42, "login_user")
```

Comment: If I change to this format the request is formed correctly but I receive an error response from the API re invalid credentials which isn't correct as credentials are correct.  I think it's required as @ Path and not @ Query.  I am upgrading from 1.9 and it was @ Path and working correctly.  Is this encoding special characters a limitation of retrofit2 or okhttp3?

Comment: I don't know about the encoding, but u used API incorrect. Can you check your request? What actually is incorrect?

Comment: I am currently upgrading from 1.9 to 2.0, in 1.9 we used the api like so `@POST("/{server}login_user&ts={timestamp}")
    @Multipart
    void loginUser(@Path(value="server", encode=false) String server,
                           @Part(Constants.USER) String username,
                           @Part(Constants.PASS) String password,
                           @Path("timestamp") Long timestamp, Callback<MDLoginModel>callback);`  This worked correctly and when testing with this the result from the server is that credentials are correct.

Comment: with the format you suggested I then get an error message from the server credentials incorrect.  I can't check the request at the moment.

Comment: check my updated answer, maybe you need formurlencoded, not form-data?

Comment: Thank you for persevering!  That fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@FormUrlEncoded` . And you don't need to include package name in all declarations! just import them! its more neat and clean!

```
  @POST("/{serverext}login_user&ts={timestamp}")
    @Multipart
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<LoginResponseModel> loginUser(@Path(value = "server", encoded = true) String server,
                                       @Part(SyncStateContract.Constants.USER) String username,
                                       @Part(SyncStateContract.Constants.PASS) String password,
                                       @Path("timestamp") Long timestamp);
```

Comment: Hi, the package name declaration is to allow me to upgrade to Retrofit2 from 1.9 which I am currently in the process of doing.  I had already tried `@FormUrlEncoded` and it didn't work I still end up with the `?` encoded.  Thank you for your help, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Does anyone have any information on this?  As to why when I set `encoded = true` the `?` is still encoded?

Comment: if you don't want your ? to be encoded why did you made `encoded=true` ? just leave that or make it `false`

Comment: Because as per documentation https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html. setting encoded = true ensures that it is not encoded, encoded by default is false which results in items being encoded

Comment: damn! thanks for pointing that out!! sorry for the misinformation