# HTTP Request Charset with Retrofit

Tags: android, http, retrofit2

I'm having a problem trying to send some special characters in a request using Retrofit.

I'm calling a service which uses the @FormUrlEncoded annotation.
I have two parameters:

```
@Field("name") String name
@Field("password") String password
```

And the value of the parameters are:

```
name = "nuñez"
password = "asd asd"
```

When I debug the request, I can see that the value of both parameters is changing:

```
name=nu%C3%B1ez&password=asd%20asd
```

So, the service returns an error because the data is incorrect.

I try doing:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1")
```

But it does not work

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361297/issue-with-special-characters-in-retrofit-2-encoding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525433/retrofit-encoding-special-characters

Comment: All the answers in the questions didn't work for me and they don't refer to the same problem

Comment: alright , i will check it

Comment: did you try using volley and http url connection using json request?